# removing markers in mapquest android (clearing map)

Tags: android, mapquest

I'm using mapquest android in my application, I can display markers, but I want to be able to display just two markers each time, so removing existing markers if I have already displayed two.
does anyone know how can I do it ?
here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends NavigationIntentDemo {

    ArrayList<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> routeData = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    /**
     * Initialize the map.
     */
    @Override
    protected void init() {
        setupMapView(new GeoPoint(40.25f, 116.5f), 12);

        TouchOverlay overlay = new TouchOverlay();
        map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
    }


    /**
     * Construct a simple line overlay to display on the map and add a OverlayTapListener
     * to respond to tap events.
     * 
     */
        private void showLineOverlayWithPoints(ArrayList<GeoPoint> routeData) {
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setAlpha(100);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

            LineOverlay line = new LineOverlay(paint);
            line.setData(routeData);
            line.setShowPoints(true, null);
            line.setKey("Line #2");

            line.setTouchEventListener(new LineOverlay.OverlayTouchEventListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onTouch(MotionEvent evt, MapView mapView) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Line Touch!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
                }
            });
            this.map.getOverlays().add(line);
            this.map.invalidate();
        }   


    /**
     * Crude way to launch navigation to various locations based on clicking on the map.
     *
     */
    private class TouchOverlay extends Overlay { 

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {

            Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_marker);
            DefaultItemizedOverlay poiOverlay = new DefaultItemizedOverlay(icon);

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p.getLatitude() + "," + p.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                if(points.size()<2) {
                points.add(p);



                // set GeoPoints and title/snippet to be used in the annotation view 
                poiOverlay.addItem(new OverlayItem(p, "blabla", "blabla"));

                if (points.size() == 2) {

                    routeData = parser.getRoute(    points.get(0).getLongitude(), 
                                                    points.get(0).getLatitude(), 
                                                    points.get(1).getLongitude(),
                                                    points.get(1).getLatitude(),
                                                    "SPS");

                    if (routeData != null)
                        showLineOverlayWithPoints(routeData);
                    else 
                        Log.e("ERROR","Route data error");

                } else exit(0);

               /* poiOverlay.setOnFocusChangeListener(new ItemizedOverlay.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChanged(ItemizedOverlay overlay, OverlayItem newFocus) {
                        // when focused item changes, recenter map and show info
                        map.getController().animateTo(newFocus.getPoint());
                        Toast.makeText(map.getContext().getApplicationContext(), newFocus.getTitle() + ": " + 
                                newFocus.getSnippet(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
                    }           
                });*/

                map.getOverlays().add(poiOverlay);
                return true;

                }
                else {

                    points.clear();
                }   
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void exit(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

NavigationIntentDemo

```
public class NavigationIntentDemo extends MapActivity {

    protected MapView map; 
    protected MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
    protected Button followMeButton;

    /** 
     * Called when the activity is first created. 
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutId());

        followMeButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.followMeButton);
        followMeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myLocationOverlay.setFollowing(true);
            }
        });

        setupMapView(new GeoPoint(40.25f, 116.5f), 12);
        setupMyLocation();

       init();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the view.
     */
    protected void init() {
        this.setupMapView(new GeoPoint(40.25f, 116.5f), 12);
    }


    protected void setupMyLocation() {
        this.myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);

        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GeoPoint currentLocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation(); 
                map.getController().animateTo(currentLocation);
                map.getController().setZoom(14);
                map.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
                myLocationOverlay.setFollowing(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This will set up a basic MapQuest map with zoom controls
     */
    protected void setupMapView(GeoPoint pt, int zoom) {
        this.map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        // set the zoom level
        map.getController().setZoom(zoom);

        // set the center point
        map.getController().setCenter(pt);

        // enable the zoom controls
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }

    /**
     * Get the id of the layout file.
     * @return
     */
    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Utility method for getting the text of an EditText, if no text was entered the hint is returned
     * @param editText
     * @return
     */
    public String getText(EditText editText){
        String s = editText.getText().toString();
        if("".equals(s)) s=editText.getHint().toString();
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Hides the softkeyboard
     * @param v
     */
    public void hideSoftKeyboard(View v){
        //hides soft keyboard
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }


}
```

Thank you

Comment: did you find answer for this?

Comment: Yes, I used onTap instead of Ontouch. But I have to check my code I don't remember what I did to limit the Marker's number. Do you still need it ?

Comment: It's always nice to post your answer, people come here later with the same problem and don't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the map before you put new markers using

map.getController().clear()

it will clear everything on map.

if you want to remove Marker only then you have to create Marker object when you add the marker on map

Marker some_Marker = map.getController().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(marker_icon).position(coordinates);

And Remove Marker

map.getgetController().removeMarker(some_Marker)